# Recomendaciones de autenticaciones en Angular 2+

Tags: autenticación, angular, buenas-prácticas

Estoy viendo el tema de autenticacion de angular, ya sea logueo, o registro usando API como Google o Facebook.

Actualmente estoy usando la version mas reciente de Angular 5, y me encuentro en la duda de qué tipo de autenticación se debería hacer. He visto que es sencillo con Firebase Auth, pero también me dijeron que hay problemas con SEO o algo así. No me terminaron de explicar bien, así que, ¿qué buenas practicas o frameworks, son mejores en cuanto a su seguridad, facilidad o flexibilidad, y por qué?

Como extra también me interesa un ejemplo o tutorial de ese tipo de autenticación.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa la documentación de google y facebook que te indica que tienes que hacer para autenticarse desde tu aplicación.

google: [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)

facebook: [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login)

github facebook: https://github.com/zyra/ngx-facebook

Answer (score 0):

Personalmente te recomendaría utilizar **Firebase** para la Auth, es mas sencillo y te ahorras mucho tiempo. 
Puedes cerciorarte en aquí en la [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/?hl=es-419) tiene vas opciones, desde Github a autenticación anónima

Answer (score 0):

Angular es un framework estable, robusto y seguro. Para la autenticación, como ya te han comentado algunos compañeros, es muy útil utilizar Firebase para todo el backend (no sólo la autenticación, sino que también puedes utilizar persistencia, storage, hosting, notificaciones push...). En cuanto a autenticación, te permite utilizar varios providers:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En caso de utilizar firebase, deberás instalar [AngularFire](https://angularfirebase.com/), ya que te ayudará en el desarrollo y se integra perfectamente con Angular, además de ofrecerte ventajas gracias a TypeScript (intellisense, tipos, etc).

En cuanto al SEO, es cierto, y hay problemas por la propia naturaleza o tecnología de las SPA (*Single Page Application*, que se renderizan sólo en cliente), y cuando los crawlers o arañas pasan por la aplicación, no son capaces de entenderla correctamente. Para ello también puedes implementar la técnica de SSR (*Server Side Rendering*) con Angular para soportar SEO, aunque tendrás que hacer más cosas, como montar un backend con NodeJS. Te dejo un enlace [aquí](https://angular.io/guide/universal).

Espero haberte podido ayudar, si tienes alguna duda, deja un comentario.